# Deserialize protobuf java array

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

Supose I have a WCF service which sends List serialized with protobuf-net. That function returns byte[], application/octet-stream.

Now, in my java application I have compiled MyClass.proto into MyClass.java and get from http the data sent before.

To deserialize 1 object I shall use

```
MyClass MyObject = MyClass.parseFrom(http_input_stream);
```

But what shall I use if an array comes...?

Comment: What do you mean "if an array comes...?" ? I'm assuming your java code is based on a .proto, which *presumably* has that data as `repeated`. It *should* just populate into the correct data structures. Assuming you managed to get the same underlying data (the `byte[]`) into java that you produced in C# (check that first: all bets are off if you haven't managed to successfully transfer the `byte[]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `List<MyClass>` is actually serialized as a sequence of `MyClass` objects, each with a standard field-header of `1`. I don't know the java API backwards: if it has a "read a sequence of items" API then: use that. However, a trusty fallback is the following, entirely compatible ".proto" fragment:

```
message Foo {
    repeated MyClass items = 1;
}
```

Load the data as a `Foo` (you might want to rename that...) and: job done.

Answer (score 2):

Well I ended up by creating another proto message

```
message MyClassCollection {
    repeated MyClass = 1;
}
```

Then compile it into java class and deserialize the incoming array like

```
MyClassCollection MyObjects = MyClassCollection.parseFrom(http_input_stream);
```